# ASP.NET beginner question: Regarding application of master page

Tags: asp.net

There's this masterpage in a folder named "Templates" in my project. When I create an aspx page in the same folder, the master page applies all right.

But when I create it outside the "Templates" folder and refer the same master page it doesn't apply well.

What is weird is, everything is getting applied all right BUT a `td`'s background color.

Why is that? What's wrong? Either nothing should be applied well or everything should be all right. Why is it that ONLY `td`'s background color is missing?

Also the pages that I am applying my master page on has got no data yet. I have just applied the master page.

I mean, obviously the address of the master page is all right, that is why it IS getting applied, just that `bgcolor` goes missing.

Sorry if it sounds like a dumb question but I am new to .NET. I am just trying out stuff.

Help?

[EDIT]

This is the address, BTW.

```
MasterPageFile="~/templates/master1.master"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the TD background color come from? If it is in a stylesheet then the CSS file is probably not referred to correctly.

Comment: +1 The stylesheet needs to be referenced like "~/Style.css", not "Style.css".

Comment: sorry it's not a bgcolor..its actually an image in the background of TD..the image is stored in some "Image" folder... I had to add "../../images" before the path of the image src..only then it gets displayed..the problem is "~/images" isn't working when it should..dunno what the problem is..any idea ?

Comment: sorted it out..image path problem it was